# Not getting exact value in Variable becasue value contains $ char

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a string "/Name Pa$Name@my"

```
    $myname  = GetContent("Name")
```

GetContent is only gets the key and gives the value for that Key. I cannot modify the GetContent function.

If i execute above, as "Pa$Name@my" contains the '$' char, $myname gives me value as "Pa@my" and ignores "$Name" content.

What can i do to get the $myname = Pa$Name@my ? Can i append some special characters while assigning the $myname variable.

Comment: How are you checking the contents of `$myname`? Does `GetContent` evaluate the value internally before returning it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your trouble comes from the fact that the var `$name` does not exist. You can use single qotes if you don't want Powershell to look for vars :

```
$a = 'Pa$Name@my'
```